# AngularJS: ng-repeat in directive with isolated scope and $last

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to catch $last property to be notified when ng-repeat finishes off. I've created special directive for that (*ngRepeatDoneNotification*). Ng-repeat applies to another element directive (*unit*). So, there is a construction with three directives:

```
<unit ng-repeat="unit in collection" ng-repeat-done-notification id="{{unit.id}}"></unit>
```

Once I set scope to be isolated, $last disappeared in my notifier directive.

```
App.directive('ngRepeatDoneNotification', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    if (scope.$last){ // ISSUE IS HERE
      window.alert("im the last!");
    }
  };
});

App.directive('unit', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {id: '@'}, // ONCE I ISOLATE SCOPE, $last DISAPPEARED
    templateUrl: '/partials/unit.html',
    link: function(scope, element) {}
  }
});
```

I've create jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4erLA/1/

How is it possible to catch this?

Comment: I don't think you can have a dynamic `id` attribute like that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to make the **isolated scope** to catch `$last`, you need to use `$parent` to refer to the parent scope like this

```
if (scope.$parent.$last) {
    $rootScope[attrs.ngRepeatDoneNotification] = "$last has been catched"
}
```

You may refactor it to make it work for both scenario or just simply duplicate it.

Comment: thanks, is there a way to detect current scope is isolated, to be able to do ngRepeatDoneNotification works in any cases? I've found scope.$$isolateBindings, but it helps only in case scope defined with non-empty hash.

Comment: @acidron That's a good question. I don't know but you can try to check whether `scope.$parent.$parent` is null, it if is null, then it should be directly inside the scope of the controller, if not it should be inside another level of scope.